# Django: Should I save Stripe responses as JSON in my models?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am currently setting up a Stripe (Standard Connect) account. I know have a general best-practice question.

One example: Creating a 'charge', Stripe is giving me back a JSON answer looking like that:

```
<Charge charge id=ch_1CizRmABvPzR13WAhFXBkrYf at 0x00000a> JSON: {
  "id": "XXX",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 900,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application": "ASDF",
  "application_fee": null,
  "balance_transaction": "XXX",
  "captured": true,
  "created": 1530428050,
  "currency": "eur",
  "customer": null,
  "description": null,
  "destination": null,
  "dispute": null,
  "failure_code": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "fraud_details": {
  },
  "invoice": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "order": null,
  "outcome": {
    "network_status": "approved_by_network",
    "reason": null,
    "risk_level": "normal",
    "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
    "type": "authorized"
  },
  "paid": true,
  "receipt_email": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "refunded": false,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1CizRmABvPzR13WAhFXBkrYf/refunds"
  },
  "review": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": {
    "id": "XXX",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": "42424",
    "address_zip_check": "pass",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "customer": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 4,
    "exp_year": 2024,
    "fingerprint": "whM4LE8uZm9vdxIa",
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "source_transfer": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

As I am now deciding about the database model and the fields, the question I am confronted with now is: Which fields do I save? (All of them, or just the one (transaction id), which I need to retrieve this charge object at a later point again.

My current approach: As of now I decided for that approach, that my database model for 'charges' will only contain a pk and a **JSON field** where I will save **all** the information and therefore I would be able to access anything, whenever need from my own database. This JSON field approach I would also use for my model with the **Stripe's account object** etc.

But first, my question is: Is this a good approach, or would you rather recommend me saving each field individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either approach is valid. You can either save just the Stripe ID and then retrieve the object from the API as you need it, or save to the your local database. There are a couple of things you might want to be aware of if going with the database approach:

- The format of Stripe's response might change in future API releases, so if you are upgrading your integration to a new API version, you may have to do migrations on your database models.
- Many objects in Stripe are not immutable, so it's possible that your 'local' view in the database becomes out of date. As a simple example, a charge may be refunded, or marked as fraud, after it has been created. You would need to use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to keep your local models up to date. If you are using Connect, the use of webhooks is heavily recommended.

The best approach might be a hybrid solution, where instead of just saving the ID, or the exact JSON from Stripe, you could define your own model with the information that is relevant to you, along with the ID. That way you get the benefit of not having to call the API to interact with your model day-to-day, but you have the flexibility of not being so tightly-coupled to the exact format of a specific Stripe version.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of data you store has more to do with your use-case than standard practice. You might want to store the customer id of person creating charge, amount charged, the date of transaction, the source used for charge (which card).

If you are allowing refunds on that charge, you might also want to store fields to do with refunds: `amount_refunded`, `refunded` etc.

Hope this helps. :)